# Gradient Descent basic algorithm overshooting and doesn't converge in python

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, gradient

So I'm new to learning ML and I am using gradient descent as my first algorithm I would like to get good at and learn well. I wrote my first code and have looked online for the issue I'm facing but due to lack of concrete knowledge I'm having a hard time understanding how I would go about diagnosing my issue. My gradient begins by approaching the correct answer and when the error has been cut by a factor of 8, the algorithm loses it's value and the b-value begins to go negative and the m-value goes past the target value. I'm sorry if I worded this odd, hopefully the code will help.

I am learning this from multiple sources on youtube and on google. I have been following Siraj Raval's math of intelligence playlist on youtube, I understood how the underlying algorithm worked but I decided to take my own approach and it seems to not be working too great. I'm struggling to read online resources as I'm inexperienced in what ever algorithm means and how it's implemented into python. I know this issue has something to do with training and testing but I don't know where to apply this.

```
def gradient_updater(error, mcurr, bcurr):

    for i in x:
        # gets the predicted y-value
        ypred = (mcurr * i) + bcurr
        # uses partial derivative formula to get new m and b
        new_m = -(2/N) * sum(x*(y - ypred))
        new_b = -(2/N) * sum(y - ypred)
    # applies the new b and m value
    mcurr = mcurr - (learning_rate * new_m)
    bcurr = bcurr - (learning_rate * new_b)
    return mcurr, bcurr

def run(iterations, initial_m, initial_b):

    current_m = initial_m
    current_b = initial_b
    for i in range(iterations):
        error = get_error(current_m, current_b)
        current_m, current_b = gradient_updater(error, current_m, current_b)
        print(current_m, current_b, error)
```

I expected the m and b values to converge to a specific value, this didn't occur and the values kept increasing in opposite direction.

Comment: What is the function you minimize? Does the idea of a "line search" tell you something? If you multiply your function by 100, can you guarantee that your algorithm finds similar steps as before?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your code correctly, I think your problem is that your taking the partial derivative to get your new slope and intercept on just one point.  I'm not sure what exactly some of the variables within the gradient_updater are, so I will try to provide an example that better explains the concept:

I'm not sure we are calculating the optimization in the same way, so in my code, b0 is your 'x' in y=mx+b and b1 is your 'b' that same equation. The following code is for calculating a total b0_temp and b1_temp that will be divided by the batch size to present a new b0 and b1 to fit your graph.

```
for i in range(len(X)):

    ERROR = ERROR + (b1*X[i] + b0 - Y[i])**2

    b1_temp = b1_temp + (1/2)*((1/len(X))*(b1*X[i] + b0 - Y[i])**2)**(-1/2) * (2/len(X))*(b1*X[i] + b0 - Y[i])*X[i]
    b0_temp = b0_temp + (1/2)*((1/len(X))*(b1*X[i] + b0 - Y[i])**2)**(-1/2) * (2/len(X))*(b1*X[i] + b0 - Y[i])
```

I run through this for every value within my dataset, where `X[i]` and `Y[i]` represent an individual datapoint.

Next, I adjust the slope that is currently fitting the graph:

```
        b1_temp = b1_temp / batch_size
        b0_temp = b0_temp / batch_size

        b0 = b0 - learning_rate * b0_temp
        b1 = b1 - learning_rate * b1_temp

        b1_temp = 0
        b0_temp = 0
```

Where batch_size can just be taken as `len(X)`.  I run through this for some number of epochs (i.e. a for loop of some number, 100 should work), and the line of best fit will adjust accordingly over time.  The overall concept behind it is decrease the distance between each point and the line to where it is at a minimum.

Hope I was able to better explain this to you and provide you with a basic code base to adjust your's upon!

Answer (score 0):

Here's where I think the error in your code lies - the calculation of the gradient. I believe that your cost function is similar to the one used in https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gradient_descent.html. To solve the gradient, you need to aggregate the effects from all partial derivatives. In your implementation however, you iterate over the range *x*, without accumulating the effects. Therefore, your `new_m` and `new_b` are only calculated for the final term, *x* (Items marked 1 and 2 below).

**Your implementation:**

```
def gradient_updater(error, mcurr, bcurr):
    for i in x:
        # gets the predicted y-value
        ypred = (mcurr * i) + bcurr
        # uses partial derivative formula to get new m and b
        new_m = -(2/N) * sum(x*(y - ypred))    #-- 1 --
        new_b = -(2/N) * sum(y - ypred)    #-- 2 --
    # applies the new b and m value <-- Indent this block to place inside the for loop
    mcurr = mcurr - (learning_rate * new_m)
    bcurr = bcurr - (learning_rate * new_b)
    return mcurr, bcurr
```

That said, I think your implementation should come closer to the mathematical formula if  you just update `mcurr` and `bcurr` in every iteration (See inline comment). The other thing to do is to divide both `sum(x*(y - ypred))` and `sum(y - ypred)` by *N* as well, in computing `new_m` and `new_b`.

**Note**
Since I do not know what your actual cost function is, I just want to point out that you are also using a constant `y` value in your code. It is more likely to be an array of different values and be called by Y[i] and X[i] respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, I used this and tweaked my error equation a little and it works now.